# will using the 2 graphics cards lower my system performance

Tags: graphics-card

my friend gave me a gaming computer from 2-3 years ago and he gave me a radeon hd6570 2gb ddr3
the old graphics card in there is a xfx geforce 9500 gt and my power supply is 460Watt can i put both graphics card in my computer the nvidia one for physx and the other better one for gaming???

Comment: I assume you want to use both cards to boost your PC's performance and I think the answer is that you most certainly can't, as far as I know computers don't or can't balance processing loads between different GPUs per se, the only way the do it is via SLI (for NVIDIAS) or CrossFire (for Radeons) which require the cards being of the same specs, RAM, frequency (radeons) or ultimately just the same (nvidias) and this require a special set of drivers too. Not to mention you can only do this with either 2-4 NVIDIAS or Radeons, but not both of them.

Comment: thank you i was just wondering but i would be better of selling it than

Comment: You can sell the older one and use the other

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't use the two cards together to increase your performance. Theres also no benefit to putting both into your computer.